# Set defaults at runtime

Tags: python

I manage a fairly large python-based quantum chemistry suite, [PyQuante](http://pyquante.sf.net). I'm currently struggling with how to set various defaults so that users can choose among different options at runtime.

For example, I have three different methods for computing electron repulsion integrals. Let's call them a,b,c. I used to simply pick the one I liked best (say, c), and have that hard-wired into the module that computes these integrals.

I have now modified this to use a module, Defaults.py, that contains all such hard-wires. But this is set at compile/install time. I would now like users to be able to override these options at runtime, say, using a .pyquanterc.py file.

In my integral routines, I currently have something like

```
from Defaults import integral_method
```

I know about dictionaries, and the .update() method. But I don't know how I would use this in real life. My defaults module looks like

```
integral_method = c
```

should I modify the end of Defaults.py to look for a .pythonrc.py file and override these values? E.g.

```
if os.path.exists('$HOME/.pythonrc.py'): do_something
```

If so, what should do_something look like?

Comment: "But this is set at compile/install time"?  Not really.  The module is executed along with everything else.  "Compile" doesn't mean much in Python.  If the module is in the user's directory instead of the installation directory, then the user can change it, right?

Comment: The sense in which I meant it was set at install is that I'm imagining a use case where a maintainer installs the software, which means that all the Defaults.py definitions are installed into the local site-packages directory. I want people to be able to change these settings easily.

Comment: "means that all the Defaults.py definitions are installed into the local site-packages"?  Why?  If you want flexibility, why install the configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your current setup, the user can change the default functions in his scripts quite easily:

```
import Defaults
Defaults.integral_method = somefunc
```

If the user adds this to his script, all your modules that use `integral_method` from `Defaults` will use `somefunc` to calculate integrals.

Comment: Ding ding ding! This should have been obvious to me, but wasn't. Seems like the easiest way to do this, since I don't actually have to do anything. Although I find the factory class solution below pretty sweet as well. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

I might do this via a factory class.

```
class IntegralSolver:
    """
    Factory class containing methods for solving integrals.

    >>> solver = IntegralSolver("method1")
    >>> solver(x)
    # solution via method1

    Can also be used directly:
    >>> IntegralSolver.method2(x)
    # solution via method2
    """
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.__call__ = getattr(self, method)

    @staticmethod
    def method1(x):
        return method1_solution

    @staticmethod
    def method2(x):
        return method2_solution
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, too. Do you think having a bunch of functions defined with lambdas so they can be called at runtime would help?

Comment: Very elegant. I normally shy away from methods like this, but your code is so clean, I can't imagine why I don't do this all the time. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your user runs the toolset. If they twiddle the python code each time, just setting a block at the top labeled OPTIONS should be good. If they run it off the command line, use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) library to allow them to switch options on the command line. Perhaps have it read the options out of a file with [configParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) to read a default file with your options, and if the user sets it, an additional file with their options.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I manually override the values in the Defaults.py module (along the lines of what sth suggested above) using argparse (or getopt for me, I'm old school)? That could be a nice slick way to add to the method that I was already leaning toward. Thanks!

Comment: I've found that the two libraries above make it very easy to transform a python script into a full blown command line program. This way you don't have to think about tokenizing the input string and parsing over it, which is complicated, you just define your flags and their defaults.